# REST XML request testing using java/selenium

Tags: java, rest, selenium

At my workplace I need to an REST API post request. In which we receive XML request, that needs to fire on some endpoint. Now I am using SOAP UI. But the thing is, I need to fire that same XML request 100 time with random values in the attribute.
     I need to use JAVA Selenium or pure Java to automate this. So that it will fire request 100/any number of times with random attribute values. I am new to Automation, I need some help doing this in Java.

Answer (score 0):

There was a thread that discussed how to use java code to do that.

[Stackoverflow - posting XML request in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735839/posting-xml-request-in-java)